# delete person with all assigned books

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, swift4

i working with swift 4 for osx.

```
   let appdelegate = NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appdelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    var people = [Person]()
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Person>(entityName: "Person")
    do {
       people = try context.fetch(request)
       for person in people {
           print("Person: ", person.name!)
           for book in person.books {
                print("Title: ", book.title!)   
           }           
       }
    }

catch { print(error) }
```

- i have to entities: Person and Books
- I can create a person
- i can create a book which will assign to a person
- and i know how i can get the information which books are assigned to
  which person (code above)

now i would like to delete a person with all assigned books.
can i do this in one step or have I request every book objectID from entity books and delete it? i tried something like this:

```
   let appdelegate = NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appdelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    var people = [Person]()
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Person>(entityName: "Person")


     people = try context.fetch(request)
       for person in people {
           context.delete(person as! NSManagedObject)
           for book in person.books {
                // request object ID of this book form books and delete it
           }           
       }


    } catch { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data provides "relationship delete rules" (see the Relationship Delete Rules section in the [CoreData Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW1)) to control what happens to related objects when an object is deleted.

In your case, if you set the delete rule for the `books` relationship on the `Person` entity to "Cascade", Core Data will automatically delete all related `Book` objects when you delete a `Person`.